# Using TSQL to Unzip a value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, gzip

How can I unzip a varbinary(max) value in a stored procedure? I'd like to implement or invoke a gunzip algorithm within TSQL code, preferably without enabling the CLR.

Comment: I'd like my alarm clock to make me a decent cup of coffee, but in the end I decided a kettle and a cafetiere were more appropriate tools for the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into
sp_OACreate
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189763.aspx

sp_oamethod
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174984.aspx

You can write the value as a file using file system object, then use a command line gunzip program on it and the read the file using FSO back.

Yes this is not practical but I am not the type of guy who thinks in terms of impossible.