# How to compress datatable column before calling stored procedure via .net?

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, datatable, dataset

I am writing a .net client to a remote sql server 2012 database. The client works by calling *stored procedures* which take *table-valued parameters* as input. The client calls these stored procedures by creating .net *datatables*, and then passing these datatables as parameters (`SqlCommand.Paramters.AddWithValue()`). The datatable is then transmitted to the sql server when I call `dataAdapter.Fill(dataset)`. One column of these datatables contains file paths, which are `nvarchar(max)`. This can make the datatable very large. This is a serious bottleneck, since the sql server is in another part of the world.  My question is: is it possible to somehow compress the file paths, so as to minimize the amount of data which flies over the internet? At what level should I do this compression? Or is some compression already being done automatically? Note: I am talking about the column but of course it is ok to compress the whole datatable. Thanks

Comment: Does your code work (other than the bottleneck)?

Comment: you could always perform this operation asynchronously. It won't solve the bottle neck but at least you could give feedback that something is happening.

Comment: Because there is no [`compatible datatype`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) in .net framework to match `sql table` type.

Comment: I am already doing it asynchronously. But a batch operation is taking more than an hour because I am passing like 10000 file paths. The size of the datatable could be compressed 99%...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any control over the remote server?  Are you able to make changes to the stored procedure?

I don't think there is a built-in connection type that supports compression (though its possible to [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454011/8262)) but if you're able to modify your approach you could fairly easily support your requirement through SQL CLR...

- Change the target sproc to accept varbinary(max) instead of a table
- Have your .NET client encode and compress the data (json maybe?) and
  then call the sproc, passing it as the binary payload
- Have the target sproc decompress and decode the binary to a table (via SQL CLR)
- ... and carry on as before

Comment: I have total control over the server. I wrote the stored procs. I have avoided SQL CLR, I don't want to introduce it now...

Comment: you say "Have the target sproc decompress and decode the binary to a table"------

How exactly? can I not do that in plain t-sql? is there an operation like UNCOMPRESS_STRING in t-sql? I could modify my stored procs to decompress the string before using them...

Comment: I don't know of any built-in method. SQL CLR is ideal for this kind of non-trivial data manipulation requirement and while you can probably [work around it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827459/using-tsql-to-unzip-a-value) you'll end up adding way more complexity doing so.